# Get number of Nth place of modified Fibonacci sequence

Tags: algorithm, math

In an interview today, I was given this sequence, which is sort of a modified Fibonacci:

1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 13, 19, 42, 61, 135, ...,

I was asked to write a function to return the number at place *n*.

So, if n = 4, the function should return 4, n = 6 return 13, etc.

As I'm sure you already noticed, the difference is that even items equal the previous 4 items, while odd items equal the previous 2.

It isn't a problem if you use recursion. That's what I did, but it's not the approach I would have liked.

The Fibonacci calculation goes something like this (in PHP):

```
$n = 17;
$phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;
$u = (pow($phi, $n) - pow(1 - $phi, $n)) / sqrt(5);
```

*$u* being, in this case, 1597.

However, I have no idea how to solve it with a modified version of a Fibonacci sequence like this one.

Comment: I'm sure they just wanted to see if you know dynamic programming.  I really doubt someone wanted you to solve an irreducible fourth-degree polynomial in an interview setting.  Just tell them "memoise the values calculated depth first".  Then wink at them and blow them a kiss.

Comment: If you break the sequence up into even and odd terms, you get a minimal polynomial of `x^3 - 3*x^2 - x + 1` for each.  This has three roots with closed-form expressions and so you should be able to apply the usual linear recurrence tricks without too much work.  [edit: on second thought, `x^6 - 3*x^4 - x^2 + 1` works too, simply take `y=x^2`.]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to compute efficiently [i.e. in O( log(n) )] sequence defined as:

```
a[2n + 5] = a[2n + 4] + a[2n + 3] + a[2n + 2] + a[2n + 1]
a[2n + 2] = a[2n + 1] + a[2n]
```

Let's define two new sequences. First one will correspond to the values of **a** on even positions, the second one to the values on even positions:

```
b[n] = a[2n]
c[n] = a[2n + 1]
```

Now we have:

```
c[n] = b[n] + c[n - 1] + b[n - 1] + c[n - 2]
b[n] = c[n - 1] + b[n - 1]
```

Subtracting the second equation from the first we get (after some transformation):

```
b[n] = ( c[n] - c[n-1] ) /2
```

Next substitute this formula into first equation to get formula for **c**:

```
c[n] = 2 c[n-1] + c[n-2]
```

Notice that this equation involves only elements from **c**. Therefore now it is possible to compute elements of **c**, using techniques described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). By transforming equations a little bit further you will be able to compute **b** efficiently as well.

Comment: This should be the best solution. `O(1)` complexity =D

Comment: Oops, I meant `O(log n)`

Answer (score 0):

> Like every sequence defined by a linear recurrence with constant coefficients, the Fibonacci numbers have a closed-form solution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

However, I do not know how to create a closed form expression for this particular sequence.

What I can add is that you can solve Fibonacci or any similar sequence without recursion, e.g.:

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/41540-fibonacci-with-no-recursion-for-fun/

So you can solve the problem using a loop rather than the stack.

Comment: You can write any algorithm without recursion, not just sequences similar to Fibonacci.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O.: I linked to an implementation of Fibonacci that does not require recursion, and in fact, used that as an interview question when hiring Engineers.  Not sure what your comment means...

Comment: I mean you can do everything with just loops in a language.  There is nothing that requires recursion.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Any arbitrary recursive solution can be rewritten as a non-recursive solution.